# What game is shown in this stock photo?

Tags: identify-this-game

I found this on Shutterstock, which is full of traditional family games and abstracts so this stood out. The image is blurry, but I figure there's enough here to recognise the game, although I don't. Anyone know what it is?

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen crystals exactly like this in Ascension, but this is not it. Perhaps a game from same publisher - they often reuse same components in different game

Comment: Those crystals are rather common.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although my initial theory didn't hold up, the Crystal track led me to this [BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/172437/games-what-have-those-little-plastic-crystals). Afterwards it was elementary.
Mystery is solved: your game most definitely is [Istanbul](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/148949/istanbul/images).

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. I've even played that & didn't spot it :)

Comment: Constantinople?